# How can I make the controller return a response in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, return-value

I installed the DataTableBundle in Symfony 4 according to this tutorial: https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#quickstart

```
 <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Controller\DataTablesTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  /**
  * @Route("/")
  */

  use DataTablesTrait;

  public function showAction(Request $request)
  {
    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
    ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
    ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
      ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
      ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
    ])
    ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
      return $table->getResponse();
    }

    $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
  }
}
```

But I get an error message by Symfony:

> Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The controller must return a
>   response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement
>   somewhere in your controller?" at
>   /Users/work/project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php line 165

I tried to change this line:

```
$this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
```

into this:

```
return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
```

but then I get a blank page with the text `Loading...` and nothing else.

list.html.twig:

```
<!-- in the <head> section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>


<!-- Insert this where you want the table to appear -->
<div id="presidents">Loading...</div>

<!-- before the closing <body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>


<!-- Insert this at the end of your body element, but before the closing tag -->
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#presidents').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }});
});
</script>
```

Services.yaml:

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.


    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Comment: Did you add the config section to your config.yml like mentioned here? https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#configuration. Because there is a default template for the table adressed, which will result to html code injected to the placeholder #presidents in your list.html.twig

Comment: @KlausSchürg I added it into my service.yaml but this was not working, so I removed it. I think I do not have a config.yaml

Comment: If I add it to services.yaml I get error `The configuration key "language_from_cdn" is unsupported for definition "datatables" in "/Users/work/project/config/services.yaml". Allowed configuration keys are "alias", "parent", "class", "shared", "synthetic", "lazy", "public", "abstract", "deprecated", "factory", "file", "arguments", "properties", "configurator", "calls", "tags", "decorates", "decoration_inner_name", "decoration_priority", "autowire", "autoconfigure", "bind" in /Users/work/project/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/work/project/config/services.yaml").`

Comment: @KlausSchürg I updated my question to show you

Comment: Did you install the assets and are they available, when opening the source-code of the rendered html? Maybe just the js is not loaded?

Comment: Yes I did via `php bin/console assets:install`.

Comment: @KlausSchürg It is working now, I installed assets again and cleared the cache. Now it works!

Comment: Happy to hear that :-) Have a nice weekend ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing return was indeed the problem. The reason for having a blank page with the word "Loading..." on it will be located in your list.html.twig. But for solving this problem you have to provide more code.